# getting file absolute path from BufferedWriter instance

Tags: java

Is there any way to get the absolute path from `BufferedWriter` ?
From the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) it seems that it is not possible but I am asking just in case anybody aware of some kind of trick...

Comment: Trick might be to use reflection. Note though that `BufferedWriter` accepts `Writer` and there are different writers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the closest you can get in Unix is to,

- use reflection to find file descriptor.
- examine the `/proc/self/fd/{fid}` to get the inode of the file and possibly the device to determine which file you are accessing.
- do a search of the device to find which filename(s) which are linked to that file.